# MINUS operation in Eloquent ORM

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is there any equivalent MINUS operation from SQL using Eloquent ORM?

For example

$model1 = Model::where('some constraints applied')
$model2 = Model::where('some constraints applied')

I want to get all models that exist in $model1 but not in $model2

Comment: You want to run this in SQL or after fetching data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

seblaze's answer looks good, though it will run 3 queries. Another option is diff() method of the Collection object:

```
$result = $model1->diff($model2);
```

This works after fetching data from the db with 2 queries, but complete set of data (unless there are more depending on your 'constraints applied').

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way i see it is :

```
//Get the id's of first model as array
$ids1 = $model1->lists('id');

//get the id's of second models as array
$ids2 = $model2->lists('id');

//get the models
$models = Model::whereIn('id',$ids1)->whereNotIn('id',$ids2)->get();
```

This is not tested code, please read more about eloquent queries [here](http://daylerees.com/codebright/eloquent-queries)